# Does the Taylor expansion and approximation centered about a point become more accurate at the point as more terms are used?

Tags: taylor-expansion, classical-mechanics

I may have done a poor job of asking this question.  You can use the sine function as the Taylor expansion as an example.

As you add more and more terms I can see how the Taylor representation of this function becomes more and more like the sine function!  I am OK with that. What I am asking is at the point 0 is the graph any more accurate past the 2nd term?

In other words assuming you are only interested in what the function looked like at the point 0 would an approximation with let us say using a hundred terms be more any more accurate than just using the first few terms.  Remember I am only interested at the point 0.

Or is it the case that no matter what point I pick the line through that point becomes more and more accurate as the terms increase?

The reason I ask this is because I am trying to understand why the action in the principle of stationary action uses only the first order terms and the higher  order terms vanish!  This happens when the Lagrangian is expanded.

All derivation examples end up using the Taylor series to write the expression and then they ignore the higher order terms.

Comment: As you can see, you now have several answers. So far, I do not think any of them tells you much about the Principle of Stationary Action. I think you would get better answers if you make this question be about the Principle of Stationary Action, walk us through the steps of an example of the principle, and point out the part that troubles you. Don't even mention a Taylor series until you actually need it while showing the example.

Comment: Some functions, like $f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2},&x\neq0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$ have Taylor series that converge but don't converge to the original function. In this example, the Taylor series centered at $x=0$ is just $0+0x+0x^2+....$. So, it converges to $0$, but the function is not identically equal to zero. Therefore, no matter how many terms you add, the approximation doesn't get better. You can also have smooth functions with divergent Taylor series. In this case adding more terms of the series gives you a worse approximation.

Comment: @David K,  yes David , I tried to do that but the question was ignored so I thought I would ask in the form of a Taylor series question.  If you are interested in what is confusing me the question I posted is "How is the Taylor expansion used in the Principle of stationary action"  I have a link to the exact equations. Maybe that was the problem. I am not allowed to use stackexchange in that manner. or you can try Youtube. search for "stationary action and hamilton's principle" at 11:12 is where my confusion is when he expands the formula...  it was posted by Lore Brashier

Comment: I don't know how to cut paste the formulas into this application that is why I have a link but I think that may be forbidden .. since one has to leave the application to see where the real question is.  I should learn the graphics

Comment: To do the formulas: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation (this does mean you have to do some editing, not just cut and paste, but that is the much preferred way to present any formulas).

Comment: Pointing someone to a PDF or (worse) YouTube video tends to discourage people from trying the question--they would have to go to a different site, then maybe do more work to find the place in the other document/video that was mentioned in the question. (I would include the PDF link anyway, but only as a reference in case someone wants to dig deeper than what you show in the question.)

Comment: By the way, I think it helps to link back to the related question when asking a follow-up question. I suppose this is the previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873934/how-is-the-taylor-expansion-used-in-the-principle-of-stationary-action

Comment: Ok Dave..I will learn the editing so then I can show the formulas that are my source of problems.  I will have to recast the question in a slightly different way as well.  thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Taylor series of $f(x)$ about $x=a$ converges to the function, then we have

$$ f(x)= f(a)+ f'(a)(x-a) + \frac {f''(a)}{2} (x-a)^2 +.....$$

As you see the first term $f(a)$ is a constant whose graph is a horizontal line.
The first two terms $f(a) +f'(a)(x-a)$ is a line with the same value and the sme slope as your function at $x=a$

When you add the third term you get a parabola  with the same value, the same slope and the same curvature as $f(x)$ at $x=a$

Thus the more terms that you add, the more details you get out of your graph.

For most functions you do not have to go too far to get a reasonable graph which is very similar to the actual graph about $x=a$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your approximation becomes more accurate (or at least it does not become *less* accurate, if $f$ is already a polynomial in the first place).

There are many variants of Taylor's theorem, but in essence we have that if $P_{a, \,k}(x)$ is the $k$-th order Taylor polynomial about $a$, then the error term

$$\epsilon(x) = f(x) - P_{a, \,k}(x)$$

is $o\left({|x-a|}^k\right)$ as $x\to a$.
In other words, by increasing $k$ you ensure the error $\epsilon$ approaches $0$ *faster* as $x\to a$.

Taylor's theorem also assures us that $P_{a,\,k}$ is unique, in the following sense:

> If $p$ is a $k$-th order polynomial and there is some $h:\Bbb R\longrightarrow \Bbb R$ with $\lim_{x\to a}\,h(x) = 0 $ and
>
> $$f(x) = p(x) + h(x)\,{(x-a)}^k,$$
>
> then $p=P_{a,\, k}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ is expanded into a power series about $x = 0$, $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n,$$ and hence $$f(0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (0^n) = c_0.$$ Thus, if $f$ represented by power series centered at $0,$ then $f(0)$ is exactly the first coefficient of this expansion. So no terms beyond the first term are necessary to give the value of $f$ at $0$. Furthermore, near $0$, all terms of the form $c_nx^n$ for $n > 0$ vanish quickly. As $n$ increases, the speed the term vanishes near $0$ becomes faster, and low-order terms give a close approximation. This is why higher order terms are dropped in derivations in physics: in the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$, they vanish.

Comment: Your last paragraph is only true if the series converges to the function (which is the same as saying "it is true when it is true"). But sometimes it isn't. The Taylor series can both diverge and converge to something that is not the original function.

Comment: @floodbaharak This pathology is why I choose to specify that $f$ is represented by a power series. I've merged the last paragraph to the previous one to make it more clear that this assumption is still being used.